# How to get the list of Collections in DocumentDB using Java API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'd like to get the list of collections in DocumentDB using Java. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/shipunyc/azure-documentdb-java/blob/master/src/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/test/GatewayTests.java#L356

> DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
>   List collections = client.readCollections(this.databaseForTest.getSelfLink(), null).getQueryIterable().toList();

Comment: what should I put as  ``.databaseForTest.getSelfLink()``? Can it be a String with my database name?

Comment: No, it's not a string with the database name. 

databaseForTest must be an instance of the Database class that was read from the system. On this instance of the class, the getSelfLink() will return the link that should be used.

it will look something like dbs/prdnAA==/ ... where prdnAA== is the resource id (or _rid) that was assigned to the database when it was created.